# Delphi SOAP server couldn’t handle SOAPAttachemnt after a non-exist method is invoke

Tags: delphi, soap

I found this problem while I solving another SOAP problem and just post here to see if anyone experienced it or have any recommendation.

**The problem:**

- SOAP server will not process method that receive TSOAPAttachment object after a non-exist method is invoked.
- The TSOAPAttachment.SourceStream become inaccessible and TSOAPAttachment.CachFile is empty after the non-exist method is invoked
- BorlandSoapAttachment(n) temp file is locked and piling up when the problem happen.
- Back to normal after restarting IIS or recycling the App Pool

**The steps of create this problem:**

- Create a simple Soap client/server application with 3 methods initially, one of them should receive and return a TSOAPAttachment, the other 2 can be anything, int or string.
- I actually followed this article http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2008/12/18/38624 to create the simple soap application, but add a method to receive and return  TSOAPAttachment. So my Interface looks like this:

code

```
  TSimpleCalculator = class(TInvokableClass, ISoapCalculator)
  private
  public
    function add(a, b: Integer) : Integer; stdcall;
    function subtract(a, b: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    function TestRequest(const Request: TSOAPAttachment): TSOAPAttachment; stdcall;
  end;
```

- Create a client of this Soap server to invoke all three methods.
- Everything should work happily at this point, ie.  the client can invoke all 3 methods and the server could response to all these successfully.

**Now, I remove the Subtract function in the server, but still using the original client.**

- Invoking both Add and TestRequest still complete successfully.
- However, after I invoke the non-exist Subtract function, TestRequest will not work anymore but the Add function still work.
- The TestRequest will have all the problem I describe above, ie. the server still response to it, but it cant get access to the TSOAPAttachment object.

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: If this is the normal behavior of Delphi SOAP, it will be quite dangerous as any client could purposely invoke a non-exist method to the server and cause the SOAP server down

Comment: So you're not handling calls to non-existant functions (meaning you're not protecting your SOAP server from being crashed by sending it meaningless noise)? This is like complaining that your app doesn't work right because you're getting an exception that's not being handled by code that should expect that exception (eg., doing division on two user-provided numbers without handing division by zero exceptions).

Comment: The docs say "THTTPSoapPascalInvoker uses the invocation registry (InvRegistry) to determine whether the interface call encoded in the incoming SOAP request matches a method on a registered invokable interface. Thus, before the invoker can handle a call, the target interface must be registered using the RegisterInterface method of the invocation registry." Also, the implementation class for that interface must be registered with the invocation registry." If the implementation isn't registered, it should do nothing; if it results in an error, handle it. It should never get to hurt the server.

Comment: Because the SOAP frame work is buggy. It should handle it correctly and return an error to client. You should create a QC

Comment: HI Ken, may I ask how to handle calls to non-existing function on the server side? Delphi seems didnt provide any access to the lower level of the SOAP communication. All I could do is, create and register the interface using InvRegistry and I have no control when a client invoking a function.

Comment: And on your second comment Ken, yes, I am expecting the server to do nothing when a client invoking a non-exist function, but it doesn’t. I don’t care what error the client is getting for now, the problem is, whenever a client invokes a non-existing function, the server will down (ie. behaves as what I describe above).
If you got the chance, could you simply create a soap server as what I described, and you should be able to reproduce the problem. To me, it looks like a Delphi bug, and it give potential to anyone to bring down a soap server.

Answer (score 0):

I used soap before, but from Java, not Delphi. But because SOAP is ubiquotus, it does not matter, it has to follow the SOAP specification. The SOAP server should return SOAP error as reply from a SOAP request that does not confront to the published methods. Your Delphi SOAP server should generate SOAP error and your Delphi SOAP client should handle the error properly. You can use a TCP traffic monitor and assign a filter so it only shows a SOAP traffic or use a SOAP traffic monitor. With a monitor you can see the request send to the server (including the message) and the reply as well. You can see the W3C online documentation about the SOAP specification. After all, your SOAP application must follow the spec.

Comment: yes, the server does return an error when a non-existing function is called, but after that the server starts behaving weird and no access to SoapAttachment on function that use SoapAttachment